# CSS: Positioning a box over top over a main div

Tags: css, html, position

I have the following HTML with the `div.logo` centered in the middle.

What would be the easiest cross browser solution to allow me to put another box `contactDetails` onto the left or right but retain the centered image?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="page-wrap">
    <header>
        <div id="logo">
                <img src="_assets/images/logo.png" width="500" height="518"/>
                <h3>New Website Soon</h3>
        </div><!--END logo-->
        <div id="contactDetails">
            <p>Content</p>
        </div>
    </header>
</div><!--END page-wrap-->
```

**CSS:**

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
body{
    background:url('../images/background.png') repeat;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
div.page-wrap,header,div.logo,h1{
    font-family: arial;
    text-align: center;
    margin:0;
}
div.page-wrap,header,div.logo,img{
    border-radius: 5px;
}
div.contactDetails{
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Putting the contact details *immediately* to the right or left, or on the right or left edge of the page?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I was thinking equal distance from the image and the edge of the page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Position the contact box absolutely.

For what it's worth, none of your CSS above will work because you're using a dot to signify the class of the div, rather than a # pound sign to signify ID of the div (`div.logo` corresponds to `<div class="logo">`, `div#logo` corresponds to `<div id="logo">`)

```
#page-wrap {
/* parents of absolutely positioned elements must have a position */
position: relative;
}

#contactDetails {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0; 
/* you could use 'left: 0;' instead, to move to the left edge */
width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: You're just missing a semicolon after `top:0` which was affecting the `right:0` positioning. I updated here: http://jsfiddle.net/tyUEb/1/ take a look :)